# Typescript change type of the Request after checkAuth middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm pretty new to typescript and I faced the issue with extending the Request type. I actually found a solution, but it doesn't feel right to me, and seems like there might be a better way.

First, the structure. I have a middleware checkAuth that checks the Bearer token, finds the user in the database (or creates one, in case it's the first time) and adds user to the req variable.

Most people recommend modifying the Express' Request type with custom declarations. I don't like this idea, because that will put user object into all requests, even before I actually save user into req.

Another solution is what I use now:

```
interface ReqWithUser extends Request {
    user?: {
        ...
    }
}
```

This allows me to declare `req: ReqWithUser`. But there's a flaw. When I try to access `req.user`, typescript is telling me that it's possibly undefined. Well, that's exactly what I declared with `user?:`. If I don't put a question mark there, then typescript is mad in router, saying `Property 'user' is missing in type Request`. That's fair. One of the solution is to use `req!.user`. Solves all problems, but it still feels imperfect to me. I know the `req.user` is there, it's not optional, otherwise checkAuth would fail and return 401. If it didn't, the user is there. What feels like the right solution is somehow modify the req type **after** the `checkAuth` middleware. Because that's when user is added into the req. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with your types, but it's the fact that Express will always emit `Request` and not `RequestWithUser`.

So in your middleware function, you will always get a `Request`. The only reason `RequestWithUser` is acceptable is because you made it optional.

Truth is the middleware / decorator pattern doesn't work *that well* with express. You have a few options (some of which you mentioned)

1. Use declaration merging to 'patch' the built-in Request. You already mentioned you don't like this though, because it's a bit of a hack.
2. Don't use Express' middleware system and instead write something that understands how types change with decorators. I don't know exactly what this looks like, or if this has been done before.
3. Whenever you want to use `RequestWithUser` in your controllers/middlewares start off with an assertion function to ensure that `user` exists (allowing you to make it non-optional).
4. Cast to RequestWithUser, when you need it.

All these options have drawbacks:

1. You don't like for the reasons mentioned. It's not always 'accurate' so you are sort of lying to Typescript for convenience.
2. Sounds hard to do
3. Requires the use of an assertion function, which means you need to do a little extra work every time you want to use the user property. This work is not needed because *you* as developer know.
4. You probably don't like casting for the same reason you don't like to use declaration merging.

By far I think 2 is the best solution, because it gives you the advantage of typing without any hacks and without having to do the extra work of an assertion function (which happens during runtime). But it means abandoning Express' Middleware system. I wouldn't know exactly how to write this code, but I am curious how if it can be done...

FYI I opened another stack overflow question, because I am curious:

[Typescript typing for decorator middleware patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286034/typescript-typing-for-decorator-middleware-patterns)

Comment: @irondsd so what did you end up doing? I'd say most people just take door #1.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the easiest solution to take right now. But I'll look into the possibility of the second option in the meanwhile, and maybe I'll do it when most of the work is done.