# Typescript typing for decorator middleware patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am thinking about Node middlewares (in various frameworks). Often middlewares will add a property to a request or response object, which is then available for usage by any middlewares registered after it.

One issue with this model is that you don't get effective typing.

To demonstrate, here's a highly simplified model of such a framework. In this case, everything in synchronous, and each middleware receives a Request and must also return one (potentially altered).

```js
interface Req {
    path: string;
    method: string;
}

type Middleware = (request: Req) => Req;

class App {

    mws: Middleware[] = [];

    use(mw: Middleware) {
        this.mws.push(mw);
    }

    run(): Req {

        let request = {
            path: '/foo',
            method: 'POST'
        }
        for(const mw of this.mws) {
           request = mw(request);
        }

        return request;

    }

}
```

To demonstrate the application, I'm defining 2 middlewares. The first one adds a new property to `Req` and the second one uses that property:

```js
const app = new App();

app.use( req => {
  req.foo = 'bar';
});

app.use( req => {
  console.log(req.foo);
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI7IN4ChkHIAOcYAFgFzIDOYUoA5gNz6EC2E5A9gCZW30QzXAF9cuMAE8iKALLAePADYQA7nCgoAvMgAUmjAFcItKugwBKZFoB8aTC1wIlcatWQBBIkRzjCyNlVqKnlFFXVNAG0AXWtkGMd-Q2oIXUCQhWU1DQgrPH9-cmBqADpA0qJksjTVCxZ-MVYCKEMQXQszTF8mgpUwZANjWjj8grGScioAcgB6GC4uKYAaHrGCDm4+ZCmABQB5AGUAFSnVwjE15HmoXQQuEGHA5C4YZCLS8ryzgsGTfp1AvpMEMwHVvshGpdNGBDFAQANgX9EudxI07g9+nBvHEQGpPN52o4sUQSslUgisLZfM1MCV5lw4lMAEYaKb1BEwuEUlgiMG4YmklK6CnWOyjdHULgqEpKLgMIEYOkLME0znwgw8upAA)

This is a very common pattern in server-side Javascript frameworks. Unaltered this throws an error:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Req'.
```

The standard solution to this is using interface declaration merging:

```js
interface Req {
    path: string;
    method: string;
}
interface Req {
    foo: string;
}
```

This has drawbacks though. This globally makes the change to the types, and we're actually lying to typescript. The Req type will not have the `.foo` property until the first middleware is called.

So, I think this is just 'the way it is' in Express, Koa, Curveball, but I'm wondering if a different pattern is possible if we wrote a new framework.

I don't think it's possible to implement this pseudo code example:

```js
app.use(mw1); // Uses default signature
app.use(mw2); // Type of `req` is now the return type of `mw1`.
```

I'm thinking it *might* be possible with chaining:

```js
app
  .use(mw1)
  .use(mw2);
```

But I'm having a really hard time fully grasping how. Plus it gets even more complex if there is a `next` function, but lets leave that out for the sake of this question.

More broadly, my question is ... what would a great server-side middleware-based framework look like, when it's written specifically with Typescript in mind. Alternatively, maybe there are other patterns that are even more effective and I'm just too blind to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question, I don't have a full answer but I think there are some ways to approach this.

**First approach**

If you'd define middleware a bit more generic, you could just say it's a simple function:

```
type Middleware<In, Out> = (input: In) => Out
```

In an HTTP environment you would use some sort of context that contains the request data as input:

```
interface InitialContext {
  method: 'GET' | 'POST'
  path: string
  query?: Record<string, string>
  headers?: Record<string, string>
}
```

I would say the first middleware element should transform the `InitialContext` to something else. If you want to be flexible, it could be anything. More practically, you'd probably want to extend `InitialContext`. For now I'll just stick with the idea that middleware can transform the `InitialContext` into anything, and the next middleware needs to deal with that.

An approach could be to just create a function that takes in a number of middleware functions and return the result of the final piece of middleware. You'd just add as many pieces of middleware as you need:

```
function requestHandler< 
  M1, 
  M2,
  M3,
  M4,
>(
  context: InitialContext,
  middleware1?: Middleware<InitialContext, M1>,
  middleware2?: Middleware<M1, M2>,
  middleware3?: Middleware<M2, M3>,
  middleware4?: Middleware<M3, M4>,
) {
  if (!middleware1) return context
  if (!middleware2) return middleware1(context)
  if (!middleware3) return middleware2(middleware1(context))
  if (!middleware4) return middleware3(middleware2(middleware1(context)))
  return middleware4(middleware3(middleware2(middleware1(context))))
}
```

This is limited to 4, but could of course be extended to any finite number using some code generation. It works:

```
const m1 = (s: InitialContext) => s.path
const m2 = (s: string) => Number(s)
const m3 = (s: number) => `${s}${s}`

const response = requestHandler({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/blabla'
}, m1, m2, m3)
```

The nice thing about this approach is that if your second piece of middleware doesn't work with the output of your first, it'll tell you about it. And this error will be pretty clear.

The downside, apart from having to write out each middleware argument separately, is that the output type is `unknown`. This is hard to solve if you don't know upfront how many pieces of middleware will be injected.

---

**Second approach, 'reducing' middleware**

So, the next question could be: is it possible to determine the 'total' type of N pieces of middleware, combined. Looking back at our previous pieces of middleware:

```
const m1 = (s: InitialContext) => s.path
const m2 = (s: string) => Number(s)
const m3 = (s: number) => `${s}${s}`
```

You could say the combined type of these 3 pieces is `Middleware<InitialContext, string>` because the first function has `InitialContext` as input and the last one has `string` as output.

Combining them would be possible with a function that looks like this:

```
function reduceMiddleware<T extends Middleware<any, any>[]>(...middleware: T) {
  return middleware.reduce((a, b) => {
    return ((input: any) => b(a(input)))
  }) as any
}
```

Can we give this function an output type?

We could combine two middleware types together using `infer` and a conditional type:

```
type TwoIntoOne<T> = T extends [Middleware<infer A, any>, Middleware<any, infer B>] ? Middleware<A, B> : unknown
```

Testing this with the following:

```
type Combined = TwoIntoOne<[Middleware<string, number>, Middleware<number, Date>]>
```

Will give us `(input: string) => Date` or `Middleware<string, Date>` as output.

However, we need to combine not 2 but N pieces of middleware. That means we need either some sort of loop, or we reduce the types together. Reducing can be achieved using recursion, and recursion is something that Typescript types do support!

So, we could use recursion to make some type that combines N types into a single type:

```
type Combine<T> = T extends [Middleware<infer Ain, infer Aout>, Middleware<infer Aout, infer Bout>, ... infer Rest] ? 
  Combine<[Middleware<Ain, Bout>, ...Rest]> : T
```

This final type will be wrapped in an array, we can make a simple adjustment to unwrap it:

```
type Unwrap<T> = T extends [infer A] ? A : unknown

type Combine<T> = T extends [Middleware<infer Ain, infer Aout>, Middleware<infer Aout, infer Bout>, ... infer Rest] ? 
  Combine<[Middleware<Ain, Bout>, ...Rest]> : 
  Unwrap<T>
```

We can use this generic in our function that we made earlier:

```
function reduceMiddleware<T extends Middleware<any, any>[]>(...middleware: T): Combine<T> {
  return middleware.reduce((a, b) => {
    return ((input: any) => b(a(input)))
  }) as any
}
```

However, note that internally this function is not type safe. We have to overwrite the result with any to be able to run this without compiler errors. However, doing that allows us to have type-safety in the rest of our code:

```
const m1 = (s: InitialContext) => s.path
const m2 = (s: string) => Number(s)
const m3 = (s: number) => `${s}${s}`

const combined = reduceMiddleware(
  m1, m2, m3
) 

// Calculated type:
// const combined: Middleware<InitialContext, string>
```

We could simply use this middleware directly with some context as input:

```
const output = combined({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/blabla'
})
```

Or we could set up some bigger application that uses this single piece of middleware to handle a request/response cycle.

Note that although this calculated type will check if the input/output of the middleware matches up, it will not really give you any error message. It'll give you the unknown type and that will probably give you some type error when you're using the combined function. There are not really any type hints to help you solve this, so there's definitely ways to improve.

---

So to answer your question: yes, there are options to work with middleware in a more type-safe way. Combining this in an OOP approach can be tricky, but working with a single piece of middleware instead of N already makes this a bit more doable.

A very simple approach would just be to accept one piece of middleware in the constructor and expect the user to use the middleware reducer as a separate step:

```
const combined = reduceMiddleware(
  m1, m2, m3
) 

class App<In, Out> {
  middleware: Middleware<In, Out>

  constructor(middleware: Middleware<In, Out>) {
    this.middleware = middleware
  }
}

const app = new App(combined)
// Calculated type:
// const app: App<InitialContext, string>
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer, which really explains the way you can extend simple routing to have those calculated types. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Great question.
If I were in your shoes I would create a new interface that extends the `Request` interface.

```
interface MyReq extends Request {
  foo: string;
}

getMovies(req: MyReq, res: Response): void {
  req.foo = "Hi there setting foo";
  res.json(this.movieService.getMovies());
}
```

This is more sustainable for a large project as yours. I quickly tested it on small project I had open, and it works just fine, and without cheating the compiler :). Take a look at it:

[image]

Let me know what you think.
Cheers.

Comment: The issue with your sample is, what guarantees that `res` has type `MyReq`. What makes sure that the `foo` property was called? I assume that the decorators effectively treat the request as `any`

Comment: Hi, please ignore the decorators, and back to your question: You won't have any guarantees because `res` is just a parameter of type `MyReq` which means that in compile time nothing will happen. Be mindful that in runtime Typescript behaves just like Javascript, so if `req` parameter receives an object of another type, it will work until the application tries to access the property `foo` on it.

Comment: The real point of my question is, I want a guarantee that `req` is a `MyReq` during compile time. It doesn't sound like your solution would do this.